# My php is showing a numeric value for my list field...Why?

Tags: forms, database

In a form I'm trying to take a value a user selected from a radio button and compare it with what's in the database. The value for the radio button is stored in $form_state['storage']['level'].

The list field in my resource type for this set of items is set as follows:

Novice|Novice
Experienced|Experienced
Professional|Professional

And yet, when I echo out the value in $form_state['storage']['level'] it just gives me what appears to be the delta and not the value of the field. Would someone please enlighten me as to how the value is obtained in php code?

Comment: Where is your code? Validate function, submit function or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi. I've tried it in the submit handler as well as the function the submit handler sends the user to AFTER submitting the form. Here's the code I'm using to echo:

    echo $form_state['storage']['level'];

Comment: dsm the $form_state var. Usually the values exist in $form_state['values']...

Comment: One line of code is not enough. Also what is the expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$form_state['values']` instead of `$form_state['storage']`.

Check out the [$form_state keys](https://www.drupal.org/node/1850410) for a bit more information.

Comment: Thanks. I tried dsm()ing the values and just get 0, 1, and 2. Moreover, when I use $form_state['values'] I just get 'array' when I echo it out. Maybe it's the way I'm storing the information to begin with? Ugh this comment box is so limited. Ummm...so when I setup the radio boxes that users select from I use the following: 
    '#options' => array(
  t('Grant writing'),
  t('Grants Research'),
  t('Grants Management'),
  t('Strategic Planning'))
  );
That apparently gets read by the system as 0, 1, 2, or 3 anad not the options themselves. Is there a way to get the actual values?

Comment: $form_state['values'] is an array so you can't echo it. Use dpm() or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to compare a field value to hide or alter other filds field dependecies module might help you